# Creating a basic user login. $_SESSION is throwing me errors

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm trying to make a basic user login.  In the PHP page that logs the user In I'm getting errors.  It works, but has errors at the top of the page.  I'm using:

**UPDATE:**

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username && $password)
{

    $connect = mysql_connect('hidden') or die ('could not connect');
    mysql_select_db('hidden') or die ('could not connect to the database');

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if ($num_rows!=0)

        {
            //code to login

            while ($row  = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query))
            {
            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];
            }

            //check to see if username/password match

            if ($username==$dbusername && $password==$dbpassword)
            {

                echo "You're in!  <a href=\"member.php\">Click here</a> to enter the member area";
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

                }

                else                
                    echo "Incorrect username/password";
                    }

                    else
                        die('That user does not exist');
                        }

else
    die('Please enter a username/password');

?>
```

This is the error if it helps:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/16/7554016/html/grahamcaldwell/DrumChum/login.php:6) in /home/content/16/7554016/html/grahamcaldwell/DrumChum/login.php on line 16
```

**UPDATE**

Problem solved.  I had to put session_start(); before even the DOCTYPE.

Comment: Interesting, the line numbers are strange. Are you sure you are running this script directly?

Comment: Sry, I had the errors from the wrong page.  I'm doing essentially the same thing with session_start(); and $_SESSION on that page though.  It's Updated to the correct errors

Comment: Your code is open to sql injection AND you are storing plain text passwords. Very bad idea...

Comment: Can you suggest a good tutorial that discusses avoiding that problem?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the session is probably because of the warning about the unexpected character. Maybe that warning is causing output to be sent to the buffer which is triggering the session error.

Comment: I Updated it.  Not, sure what unexpected characters you're referring to.

Comment: Your original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7046947/1 had "Warning: Unexpected character in input: ''' (ASCII=39) state=1 in /home/content/16/7554016/html/grahamcaldwell/DrumChum/member.php on line 16" as a warning before the session_start warning. That's what I was referring to. Glad you figured out the problem. You should accept an answer that suggested the early output as the solution.

Comment: Are you supposed to put <?php session_start(); ?> above the DOCTYPE?  I've seen examples where it's otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have two problems:

(1) You put an html comment in your php. Your php won't run at all while that's in there.

(2) And you have to put your session work before any output is sent to the buffer. So just swap your echo and $_SESSION lines and you'll be all set.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a **{** after **else**
also

```
session_start();
```

need to be at the top before anything. line 16 would suggest there is something else before that